# MVC Questionnaire App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently building a survey/questionnaire app where the admin user can create questionnaires with multiple sections and questions under those sections.

Response:

```
public ActionResult AnswerQuestions(int ID, Response model)
    {

        model.Answers = model.Answers.Where(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.TextAnswer) || a.RatingAnswer.HasValue).ToList();
        model.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        model.QuestionnaireID = ID;            

        db.Responses.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Responses", new { id = ID });


    }
```

At the moment i am using the above code to gather the answers from each question and store it but it is creating a new response each time. Can someone please help me so that I could use an existing "response" and still push the answers to the database.

View Code :

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AnswerQuestions", "Responses", new { id = Model.QuestionnaireID })" method="post">
<div class="well well-small">
    <h4>Questions - @ViewBag.ResponseID</h4>
</div>
<ul class="unstyled bordered skip-first">
    @foreach (var question in Model.SectionVM.Questions)
    {
        <li class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <input type="hidden" name="Answers.Index" value="@question.QuestionID" />
                <input type="hidden" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].QuestionID" value="@question.QuestionID" />
                @Html.Raw(question.Question1)
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                @if (question.QuestionType == "Text")
                {
                    <input class="span3" type="text" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].TextAnswer" />
                }
                @if (question.QuestionType == "Rating")
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].RatingAnswer" value="1"/><p>Don’t Know</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].RatingAnswer" value="2" /><p>Not us</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].RatingAnswer" value="3" /><p>Somewhat true of us</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].RatingAnswer" value="4" /><p>Mostly true of us</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Answers[@question.QuestionID].RatingAnswer" value="5" /><p>That’s us</p>
                }
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you asking. `db.Responses.Add(model);` adds a new `Response` to the database. What is it you actually want to do. And showing your models would help (particularly to help fix that awful manual html your generating)

Comment: I've added the database structure. My application process works like - Admin - Creates Questionnaire -> Creates Section -> Creates Questions. After that the User will answer that questionnaire from the list by - Creating a Response -> which populates all the sections and from that select a section to answer the questions within.

Comment: I'm actually using an application found online - https://github.com/jpo/aspnet-mvc-survey-tool - to help me, thats why I have the manual html. What I'm asking is how do I gather and store the answers(which it is doing) but without having to create a new Response each time as I've already created the "Response"

Comment: That has nothing to do with having to generate manual html. Hard to understand what your wanting to do. Your current code adds a new response. If you want to update an existing response in the POST method, then get the original from the database based its ID property, update its properties based on the posted model, mark it as `EntityState.Modified` and save it.

Comment: I only mentioned the Html because you mentioned it earlier. I've tried 'EntityState.Modified' already but the answers I'm retrieving in the code above 'model.Answers = ...' doesn't save to the database. It only saves when adding a new response for some reason.